# Add Restkit relationship mapping with key path different than relationship name

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm attempting to add a relationship mapping to one of my request mappings.

The POST request should send body content as such:

> {"account":{"key":"the_key_goes_here","terms_of_service":1,"person_attributes":{"email":"test@example.com"}}}

I have setup the account mapping to be:

```
NSMutableDictionary *accountAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: @{@"key":@"key",@"terms_of_service":@"terms_of_service",@"source":@"source"}];
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:accountAttributes];
```

Now, in an attempt to add the person_attributes to the request, I do the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *userAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: @{@"first_name":@"first_name",@"last_name":@"last_name",@"email":@"email"}];
RKObjectMapping *userMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:userAttributes];
[requestMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"person" mapping:userMapping];
```

However, this always sends as:

> {"account":{"key":"the_key_goes_here","terms_of_service":1,"person":{"email":"test@example.com"}}}

In an attempt to change *person* to *person_attributes* I modify the relationshipmappingwithsourcekeypath to:

```
[requestMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"person_attributes" mapping:userMapping];
```

But, it fails with an error every time, stating: `the entity Account is not key value coding-compliant for the key "person_attributes"`

I understand this is because the `Account` doesn't have a `person_attributes` value. Is there a way to add the keypath as `person` but have it send as `person_attributes`?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `RKRelationshipMapping` class and the `relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:toKeyPath:withMapping:` method to create the relationship and then set it with `addPropertyMapping:`.